# Android - Overlay with Button Not Responding Correctly

Tags: android

I have an overlay that covers my entire screen to provide a simple message when the user launches the app for the very first time. On this overlay is a single button that dismisses the overlay (by setting its visibility to gone). I have a catch-22 that I don't know how to resolve.

First, the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_rootview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="Activity.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_content"
        layout="@layout/main_content"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="#B3000000">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button dismiss"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/ok"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The very first time they launch the app, I set this overlay to be visible. I want them to be able to click the button, which will set the visibility of the overlay to `View.GONE`. As this code stands, they can click the button and all is well. However, if they click anywhere else on the overlay, the click passes through the overlay and the content behind the overlay responds as if the overlay was not present. I want this overlay to absorb the click, and only respond to the button.

So, the obvious response is to add `clickable="true"` to the overlay, right? But then, the button itself doesn't respond to the click and the user is stuck on the overlay, thereby defeating the entire purpose of the overlay. Sometimes, if I wait long enough, the button click will occur, but if this happens at all, it is an unacceptably long delay before the button will respond.

How can I get the button to respond to a click and at the same time have the overlay consume all other tap events? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Write onClick or onTouch event for your parent relativelayout of your overlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it is not the cleanest solution, but you can set onclickListener event on the overlay.
for example

```
RelativeLayout overlay = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main_overlay);
overlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

});
 //button click
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button_dismiss);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //button action
    }

 );
```

Comment: I tried this, but I still have the same issue with unresponsiveness. I'm going to mark this as the answer, because I think that it solves my issue. My guess is that there is something else going on with the app that is delaying the click response. Thanks!